# Get selected options and pass it using $http in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I am trying to pass the selected option value calling on the function on change.

```
<div class="col-md-4">

  <select id="mkSelect" ng-model="formData.mk" name="mkSelect" ng-options="mk.MkIdLabel group by mk.FY for mk in mks" ng-change="update()" class="form-control">
  </select>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.update = function() {

  // this displays the MarketId value in the log
  console.log($scope.formData.mk.MarketId);

  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'getMailStatus.php',
      // but while trying to send to "getMailStatus.php" it says its undefined 
      data: $.param($scope.formData.mk.MarketId),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);


      if (!data.success) {
        // if not successful, bind errors to error variables

      } else {
        // if successful, bind success message to message
        $scope.message = data.message;
      }
    });

};
```

The `console.log` displays the selected id , but when I try to pass the same using `$http` it says undefined (`$scope.formData.market.MarketID = undefined`)

Can anybody point me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using $.param() around the data you are trying to post?

Comment: I tried just plain { mkId : $scope.formData.mk.MarketId }  did not work so i just tried maybe serializing it i will be able to access it from getMailStatus.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.param needs an object, not a simple value.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Try with this:

```
data: $.param({mkId: $scope.formData.mk.MarketId}),
```

Comment: yeah i just tried that this worked
data: $.param({ 'mkId': $scope.formData.mk.MarketId })